# Math formula of n-th member with progression

Tags: c

How to implement the following formula in any programming language:

> 1/sin(1) + 1/(sin(1)+sin(2)) + ... + 1/(sin(1) + sin(2) + ... +
> sin(N))

That's the best I did.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    float a, c, s;
    printf("N = ");
    scanf("%f", &n);
    s = 1 / sin(1);

    for (a = 2; a <= n; a++)
    {
        c = s + (1/(sin(a-1)+sin(a)))
    }
    printf("%f", s);
}
```

Comment: The key thing to note is that there are two sums involved in that formula: the outer sum, and the sum in the denominator. Try to solve it with two nested `for`-loops first, and then try to see if you can simplify it back to one `for`-loop. Also, you assign values to `c` but you never read the value of `c`.

Comment: You need 2 loops. Someting like : global_sum = 0; for (i = 1; i <= N; i ++) { sum = 0; for (j=1; j <= i; j ++) { sum+=sin(j);} global_sum += (1 / sum); } printf("Result: %f\n", global_sum);

Comment: Try something like `sinsum += sin(k); seqsum += 1 / sinsum;`. I'll let you figure what loop those statements should be in.

Comment: Aside: never use `float` when you can use `double`, especially with a progression. Apart from some restrictive situations, computers are now powerful enough to handle `double`, despite the examples in textbooks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C#:

```
 public double getFormula(int n)
    {
       double sum = 0;
       for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            double denom = 0;
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
            {
                denom += Math.Sin(j);
            }
            sum += 1 / denom;
        }
        return sum;
    }
```